# Test Automation for progres bar

Tags: automation, progress-bar

When I donwloading some files, system shows progress-bar and this is real challenge.

I can't imaging that how can I verify this progress-bar

Just tell me how you can verify it using any automation tool!

Comment: why do you need to do that? to check if your browser is working properly?

Comment: Just verify that the progress-bar is worked correctly. Not inverter loading, or done before file is downloaded completely

Comment: Which OS, browser or application type do you need to verify?

Comment: Windows, desktop application and progress-bar as I've told

Answer (score 0):

Python GUI automation package [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) contains ProgressWrapper for native progress bar (class_name="msctls_progress32"). It has methods GetPosition(), SetPosition(pos), GetState(), GetStep() and StepIt(). I'm monitoring questions tagged "pywinauto". Feel free to ask about any details.